# how to implement multiple data-transformers in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am looking for a way to implement multiple data-transformers for one entity.

I am adding forms in a FormType like this:

```
//RegistrationFormType.php

...

$sectionsForm = $factory->createNamed('sections', 'form', null, array(
    'label' => false,
    'auto_initialize' => false
));


foreach ($sections as $key=>$section) {

    $sectionform = $factory->createNamed('section_'.$section->getId(),'form', null, array(
        'label' => $section->getName(),
    ));

    $formQuestions = $section->getFormQuestions();
    foreach ($formQuestions as $formQuestion) {

        $sectionform->add('question_'.$formQuestion->getId(), 'text',array('attr'=>...));

        ...        

    }

    $sectionsForm->add($sectionform);
}

$form->add($sectionsForm);

$builder->addModelTransformer(new RegistrationFormToArrayTransformer($em));
```

Now in the ModelTransformer, I am transforming the RegistrationForm entity like this:

```
$sections['section_'.$sectionId]['question_'.$questionId] = ...
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? My source code is getting quite messy and was wondering if I can somehow have multiple array-transformers, one for each entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a transformer on each fields yes :

```
   $sectionform->add(
      $sectionform
         ->create('question_'.$formQuestion->getId(), 'text',array('attr'=>...))
         ->addModelTransformer(/* your transformer */)
   );
```

Comment: actualy i am getting an error with this: Attempted to call method "addModelTransformer" on class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form".